# Getting cookie.load('csrftoken') undefined in react

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, react-cookie

I am sending axios.put request on my **Django** back-end (DRF). I am using **react**. GET request seems to work nicely. This is my code:

```
const options =  {headers: 
  {"X-CSRFToken": cookie.load('csrftoken')
}}

axios
.put(`/api/shippers/${values.id}/`,values, options)
.then(res => {
  console.log(res)
  return res
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
})
```

But all I get in cookie.load('csrftoken') is **undefined**. Even though csrftoken is set on my browser cookies.

[image]

Comment: What package are you using for accessing cookies? `react-cookie`?

Comment: I believe he is actually using [React-cookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookies)

Comment: Yes, I am using react-cookie to get the csrftoken value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this mystery by myself. Actually, I could not able to read csrftoken cookie from the browser using react cookie.load function. Because, in my Django back-end **CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY** is set to True. According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-httponly), if this value is set to True, you can not read the csrftoken value using JavaScript. The workaround was to set this value to False and now cookie.load working fine.

The similar is the case with session_id, that you must set **SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY** to False.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks. I was stuck at this for quite some time.

Comment: Isn't this a security flaw?

Comment: Seems like there is no point in using CSRF, if you're going to ignore it by setting HTTPONLY to False.

Comment: @degun so how do you make this work? Sometimes someone just want to get a basic login view done, instead of worrying about future hacking attacks...